# React page gives back 404 page after refresh

Tags: reactjs, http, session, networking, solidity

I have a decentralized app with a React frontend. If I go to the homepage (https://app.valerianprotocol.com/), everything works fine and I can refresh the page without any problem. On the other hand, if I navigate to another page (for example https://app.valerianprotocol.com/pool), I will get a 404 page if I refresh. I have been debugging for 3 hours but I couldn't find anything.
Can someone help me with what can be the problem?
Maybe the page doesn't save the sessionid if it is not the home page?

Comment: Is the pool page content related to the cookies ? Can we get some code of this page ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when using react with a router library (e.g React-router) you are not fetching the page "/pool" you simply change the content of the main html element inside `index.html`, and it works fine if you use links and navigation inside the React application. But when loading a page which is not the root, the server will try to serve the folder `/pool` which doesn't exist so it returns a 404 error. The options to solve this is to switch to a `HashRouter` for example or change the server configuration to redirect all into `ìndex.html`. Example of `.htaccess` rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```